# AWS Lambda running a zip package created in windows

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, virtualenv, aws-lambda

I'm freshly in AWS so this is why probably this is a basic question. Anyways the thing is that I'm to upload a zip file with my project created on my computer with **virtualenv**. So basically my environment is:

windows 10
Python 3.6
PyCharm editor
create a virtual environment for aws: virtualenv

My script requires **import** a new python library **requests**, my script below using a kind of lambda_handler (probably my code has error in that function because remember i'm new in aws and not the best in python.)

```
import requests
import datetime
import json



def handler_name(event, context):
    file = 'https://secure.bixi.com/data/stations.json'
    result = requests.get(file)
    data = result.json()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    hour = now.hour
    day = now.day
    month = now.month
    mins = now.minute


    with open('Bixi_%s_%s_%s-%s.json' % (month,day,hour,mins) , 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
    return print("download succeed")

#handler_name('n','n')
```

Once I do that I have create in my virtualenv an env to install the required python package, finally I tested my script and was executed successfully. the virtualenv has the same name as my python script you can see it and the beginning of the command line within ():

[image]

Now I just go to my project where I created my env get the folder and zipped to be upload in AWS Lambda. Unfortunately, after executing the zip file I got this message.

> START RequestId: 42e3e3ce-9aec-11e7-b97c-8116ad342de4 Version: $LATEST
>   Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named
>   'lambda_function'
>
> END RequestId: 42e3e3ce-9aec-11e7-b97c-8116ad342de4 REPORT RequestId:
>   42e3e3ce-9aec-11e7-b97c-8116ad342de4  Duration: 0.38 ms   Billed
>   Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 22 MB

**What I have tried:**
I said ok I will change my script by the default suggested script provided by Lambda as hello-world.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
    print("value2 = " + event['key2'])
    print("value3 = " + event['key3'])
    return event['key1']  # Echo back the first key value
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

Unfortunately, guys when I run my function again that returns the same message. Probably my error is when I'm creating the virtualenv but well I really don't know how to figure it out. I appreciate if someone can give me a hand with that. Thanks.

**Update**
Based on a couple of answers I have verified my project and I realized two things:

1. the name used in my function was not updated with the right file name
2. I was not zipping really well my project

For the second point I just set the right name in aws lambda as: bixi_import.lambda_handler

For the first point I created again a virtual env and then I saw in my file system that created a new folder file for this environment  then I downloaded the required package I went to the path site-packages within my virtual environment I just copied the python file and then carefully i did a crt+a for all files and created my zip  to ensure that Lambda will be able to read directly all files without go thru a folder.

thanks to @Michael in point 2 and @Kannaiyan in point 1.

Comment: The common cause of this error is zipping the folder, instead of zipping only the files inside the folder.  If done correctly, when you take your zip file and open it up, there would **not** be a folder inside the zip file called `bixi_import` with `bixi_import.py` inside the folder.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks so much for you support check out my post edition in the update part I can not tag these comments as a solution but basically you and the post below was the solution and finally I understood how lambda read the project thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation,

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
    print("value2 = " + event['key2'])
    print("value3 = " + event['key3'])
    return event['key1']  # Echo back the first key value
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

If you store this in a file called lambda_function.py.

The handler configuration for this function is, **lambda_function.lambda_handler**

> Format is  filename(without extension).functionname

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html

Comment: Good comment buddy I will retry and I'm back thanks so much I hope have been enough clear on my comment

Comment: If it does not answer your question, please leave a comment here and we can see what is going on.

Comment: thanks buddy my issue has been figured it out check my edition post in the update part.